# Navigate to next and previous subviews (Like a menu)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view, subview

I would like to create what you can think of as a menu in a subview of an IOS app. I have created the subView, but when I try to use the following line.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true )
```

I am not sure if I am doing think incorrectly, or am misunderstanding how subviews work. I was hoping to add "next" and "back" buttons to a subview and have the subviews animate from right to left as they transition between each other while staying in the same parent view the whole time. I have been following the link, http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/15/swift-swift-programmatic-navigation-view-controllers-in-swift/, to help understand pushing and poping views.

All help is welcomed. If someone responds with code, I would prefer it be in Swift.

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You could argue that my answer is more of a comment, but I need the formatting provided by an answer, so I am going to "answer" as best I can.

Your question is vague and incomplete.

Views and view controllers are completely different animals. A `UIViewController` is an object that manages a set of views, usually the entire screen. You can push view **controllers** onto a navigation stack. `UIView`s are individual objects that are displayed on the screen. Examples of `UIView`s are buttons, labels, text fields, etc.

If you don't use the right terminology, it's hard to tell what you are actually trying to do, and what you are *actually* doing.

You can push a view **controller** onto a navigation controller. You cannot push a **view** onto a navigation controller.

You need to explain how your storyboard is laid out, how your navigation controller is set up, how the current view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack, how your new view controller is created, and what triggers it being pushed onto the stack.

You need to explain what you mean by a "subview". View's can have subviews. View **controllers** can contain child view controllers that manage a part of the parent view controller's frame.

Comment: Thanks Duncan! You brought up a couple points that I would like to look into over the coming days and will get back to this thread once I have finished. I think I should do a little more research and refine my question. Thanks for being patient, I'm fairly new to ios development.